# How to get UTC offset in javascript (analog of TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset in C#)

Tags: c#, javascript, client-side

In C# you can use

```
System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(someDate).Hours
```

But how can I get UTC offset in hours for a certain date (Date object) in javascript?

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-get-timezone-offset/ ?

Comment: Your C# code is broken for offsets that aren't a multiple of a full hour.

Answer (score 48):

Vadim's answer might get you some decimal points after the division by 60; not all offsets are perfect multiples of 60 minutes. Here's what I'm using to format values for ISO 8601 strings:

```
function pad(value) {
    return value < 10 ? '0' + value : value;
}
function createOffset(date) {
    var sign = (date.getTimezoneOffset() > 0) ? "-" : "+";
    var offset = Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset());
    var hours = pad(Math.floor(offset / 60));
    var minutes = pad(offset % 60);
    return sign + hours + ":" + minutes;
}
```

This returns values like "+01:30" or "-05:00". You can extract the numeric values from my example if needed to do calculations.

Note that `getTimezoneOffset()` returns a the number of minutes difference from UTC, so that value appears to be opposite (negated) of what is needed for formats like ISO 8601. Hence why I used `Math.abs()` (which also helps with not getting negative minutes) and how I constructed the ternary.

Comment: Perfect! +1 for no external libraries and properly handling non-60 minute offsets.

Comment: Is there a case when offset can contain a value for minutes which is not zero e.g. +03:45 ? I guess not, therefore it could be even simplified to take into account hours only.

Comment: @DarkoVasilev yes, there are several timezones with offsets that are not to the hour. For example, India is at UTC+5:30. There's a New Zealand / Chatham Islands timezone at UTC +12:45 / +13:45

Answer (score 21):

I *highly* recommend using the [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com/) for time and date related Javascript code.

In which case you can get an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted UTC offset by running:

```
> moment().format("Z")
> "-08:00"
```

Comment: Is there a clean way to get an integer value for UTC offset from moment.js?

Comment: @quemeful utc offset is not necessarily in full hours. It can be 15 mins for instance. So you can get a decimal of hours -8.5 or an integer of mins. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Answer (score 16):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var d = new Date()
var gmtHours = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
document.write("The local time zone is: GMT " + gmtHours);

</script>
```