# How to get "GMT+5:30" from javascript Date function?

Tags: javascript, date

I am using JavaScript Date function, `new Date).toString()` and getting result like this `Wed Jun 28 2017 10:31:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` , But I require the GMT value like this

Result:   `Wed Jun 28 2017 10:31:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Require: `GMT+05:30`

How can I get this?

Comment: hint: `'Wed Jun 28 2017 10:31:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'.replace(/GMT\+(\d\d)(\d\d)/, 'GMT+$1:$2')`

Comment: Actually a better duplicate could be found searching on how to split a string

Comment: use moment.js better for all kind of date function

Comment: @mplungjan—thinking about it further, does the OP simply want "GMT+0530"? If so, then *getTimezoneOffset* may be involved.

Comment: @mplungjan I need string like this - "GMT+05:30"

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*How to get UTC offset in javascript (analog of TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset in C#)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149556/how-to-get-utc-offset-in-javascript-analog-of-timezoneinfo-getutcoffset-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
"Wed Jun 28 2017 10:31:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)".match(/GMT\+[0-9]+/)[0];
```

Comment: This assumes that Date.prototype.toString returns a string in that format in every implementation. However, the return value is implementation dependent, so you can't rely on that. And you certainly can't rely on the sign always being "+".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
console.log(new Date().toString().match(/([A-Z]+[\+-][0-9]+)/)[1]);
```