# Set UTC -5 offset in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, utc

Anyone know how I would modify the following to reflect a UTC offset of -5? This is the entire function, so it may be more than what actually needs to be modfied. Thanks

```
    function makeUtcWrapper(d) {

    function addProxyMethod(sourceObj, sourceMethod, targetObj, targetMethod) {
        sourceObj[sourceMethod] = function() {
            return targetObj[targetMethod].apply(targetObj, arguments);
        };
    };

    var utc = {
        date: d
    };

    // support strftime, if found

    if (d.strftime != undefined) {
        addProxyMethod(utc, "strftime", d, "strftime");
    }

    addProxyMethod(utc, "getTime", d, "getTime");
    addProxyMethod(utc, "setTime", d, "setTime");

    var props = ["Date", "Day", "FullYear", "Hours", "Milliseconds", "Minutes", "Month", "Seconds"];

    for (var p = 0; p < props.length; p++) {
        addProxyMethod(utc, "get" + props[p], d, "getUTC" + props[p]);
        addProxyMethod(utc, "set" + props[p], d, "setUTC" + props[p]);
    }

    return utc;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If d is supposed to be a Date object, you can do this:

```
d.setHours(d.getHours() - 5)
```

But note that this is a duplicate: [How to get UTC offset in javascript (analog of TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149556/how-to-get-utc-offset-in-javascript-analog-of-timezoneinfo-getutcoffset-in-c).